# In a vector/list, are you actually applying it to the object? (C++)

Tags: c++, vector

Let's say I have a vector:

```
vector<Block> myBlocks;
```

And let's say I do this:

```
Block b(10); //Let's assume this will set b's variable: x to 10
myBlocks.push_back(b); //Add it to the vector/list
```

Now, what if somewhere else I did this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<myBlocks.size(); i++){
    Block c = myBlocks.at(i);
    c.x = 15; //Will this work?
}
```

Where I put: `c.x = 15;`, is that actually setting that block's x position to 15?
Or is it only setting the **temporary** block's x position to 15?
If it's only setting the temporary block, how do I set it for the actual block?

Answer (score 6):

```
Block c = myBlocks.at(i);
```

Here `c` is a *copy* of the value contained in `myBlocks`.

```
Block& c = myBlocks.at(i);
```

Here `c` is a *reference* to (i.e., an *alias* of) the value contained in `myBlocks`.

I suspect you want the latter.

Answer (score 2):

> Where I put: "c.x = 15", is that actually setting that block's x position to 15?

No.

> Or is it only setting the temporary block's x position to 15?

Yes.

> If it's only setting the temporary block, how do I set it for the actual block?

```
myBlocks.at(i).x = 15 ; // Assuming x has a public access.
```

---

```
Block c = myBlocks.at(i);
```

`myBlocks.at(i)` returns the object which is copied to `c`. So, the objects (object in the vector, c) are two different objects with their own members ( assuming the class has no raw pointers ).

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
  Block& c = myBlocks.at(i); // note reference here
  c.x = 15; //Will this work?
```

Yours will work too but will do nothing at the end.

Answer (score 1):

What you're working with the copy of the original element.

I would suggest you to prefer using idiomatic `iterator` as:

```
for(std:vector<Block>::iterator it=myBlocks.begin(); it!=myBlocks.end(); it++)
{
    it->x = 15 ;// this will work - will update the actual element, not its copy!
    (*it).x = 15 ;// this will also work
}
```

Comment: @6502:  Why unrelated? He asked *If it's only setting the temporary block, **how do I set it for the actual block?***.

Comment: Thank you for that, I understand that it's just a copy now. However, I'm confused as to why your suggestion for iterating through the vector list is more efficient than mine? What is the difference exactly? Or is my method prone to exceptions?

Comment: Unrelated is the iterator stuff (that seems to be your main concern in this answer)... about the assignment your're not explaining anything here. This is IMO a bad answer (given this specific question, of course... it would be a great answer for a different question).

Comment: @6502: I thought other answers explained that pretty well, so I didn't feel the need to repeat that. I wrote what other answers are lacking : `iterator`. If that makes my answer "related", then I've added one line telling what he is doing.

Comment: @6502 - This loop actually does what the OP's loop wanted to do (?)

Comment: Don't both loop methods have the same result anyways? What's wrong with the original?

Comment: @vectorMania: Yeah both loop approach do exactly the same thing (if you store the returned value in *reference* of course). But why I'm suggesting this because almost all the template algorithms  work with iterators, so its better if you too make a habit of using `iterator`. That is more C++-style coding. [I again emphasize all algorithms such as `std::for_each`, `std::sort`, `std::copy`, `std::remove`, and so on, use iterators.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/)

Comment: @vectorMania - your *original* loop is creating copies. This does not. By using an iterator you can act directly upon the objects in the vector. If you don't have another reason to assign a reference to a local variable, this is IMO a cleaner approach.

Comment: @6502: What is questionable about it? Just another dialect of iterating loop. What dialect to choose depends on the loop body. If the code uses sequential number of element as not just iterating index for this container then IMO using index is more natural otherwise iterator is a good choice. I agree that this answer is vaguely related to the question asked. It just less likely to make such errors (and to ask such questions :) ) if you use iterators.

Comment: @vectorMania: The difference is that in your code `myBlocks.at(i);` would lead to minor performance penalty compared to iterators (due to index range checking inside of vector::at(i) that you don't need here) but if you would use `myBlocks[i];` instead then would be no real difference (except style of course).

Comment: @Serge Dunich: Language matters. C++ syntax for iterator types sucks and will clutter your code. The dream of writing C++ code that is independent of container type is ... well ... just a dream except most trivial cases (I you would like to have some IMO nice and pragmatic view on the subject my suggestion is to read Meyers). I personally do not like to punish myself and readers of my code with cluttered syntax unless there is a payoff. In this case there is no payoff at all.

Comment: @6502: I agree that style matters but "C++ syntax for iterator types sucks" is nothing more than your personal opinion. For the most C++ programmers iterator syntax is perfectly familiar and so easy-readable.

Comment: @6502: I would say : if you're working with C++ template, then you should make a habit of using such "sucking" syntax. Templates are all about them. You cannot imagine C++ template code, without iterators. So its better if C++ programmers soon get familiar and comfortable with them.

Comment: @Serge Dunich: sure it's my opinion. Not only mine however as apparently they tried (only ten years late) to fix the problem in C++0X (Stroustrup himself realized in the beginning how bad it was if the suggestion was to create nicknames and be liberal with typedefs). Even a few compiler implementers apparently agree as they added non-standard extensions to be able to say for example `typeof(myblocks)::iterator`. Ah! how readable is the syntax for a interation loop if `myblock` is a map from `std::string` to `std::vector<Block>`! How funny is now refactor to a map to `std::set<Block>`...

Comment: @6502: So what is the problem of using typedefs? Nobody is forced to name class template specialization explicitly with all the parameters expanded (like in ugly error messages produced by some compilers). However specifying one template parameter (like in this example) IMO usually is even more readable than using typedef.

Comment: @6502: The answer to your question is : `typedef`. The entire standard library uses it, to simply things you think is "funny" or "sucky".

Comment: @Serge and Nawaz: I know `typedef`s, and even found myself hoping they were more powerful (template typedefs absence is a defect that must be worked around with tricks). However the problem with them for this use is the very fact that you need to pick a name. It would be so much simpler if for example a syntax like `myvect::iterator` could be used, but this is not the case. While for containers as data member of classes the annoyance isn't huge (typedef once in the class), if you need to use them as local vars it gets bigger because it's not clear what name to use and where to put typedef.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a language based on **copy semantic** so when you do something like

```
Block c = myblocks.at(i);
```

you are indeed making a copy of the block object. Note that this, in C++ lingo isn't called a "temporary"... temporaries in C++ is a very specific term meaning unnamed objects created automatically and not declared.

This copy behavior is quite different from many other languages like Python or Java where instead the approach is of **reference semantic**.

You can ask to not make a copy explicitly however by using a "reference"...

```
Block& c = myblocks.at(i);
```

and in this case when you modify `c` you are working with the original element inside the vector. Note that in this case you must pay attention to how long you keep your reference around because if for example you add an element to the vector all existing references and iterators are potentially invalidated because of vector reallocation and using them is going to summon the dreaded Undefined Behavior daemon.

If a reference or an iterator is invalidated or not depends on the type of container, on the type of operation you make on the container and onther facts like space reservation so my suggestion is to read a good C++ book to understand those parts.

Note also that both `std::vector::operator []` and `std::vector::at` actually return a reference so your code could also change the original object in the vector using the more succint and idiomatic syntax

```
myblocks.at(i).x = 15;
```